# Rails-like database migrations for Parse.com server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, parse-platform

I'm looking for a tool like rails' [`rake db:migrate`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/migrations.html)  for Parse server databases.

Best case would be it offers similiar generator-functionality like `ruby script/generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts` but general hints and tips about best-practices how to setup a good migration framework (no matter on which database / programming language) are appreciated, too!

Does anybody have some starting point for me?

Answer (score 1):

The important part of Rails schema migrations is less the generator that makes the migrations, and more the control over the migrations that get applied. Using the Rails model, you would have a **schema_migrations** table that has a **versions** column, which holds a yyyymmddhhmmss timestamp. Then name schema migration files with the same version filename (plus appending whatever you want).

Every time a migration is run, get all the versions from the **schema_migrations** and a directory listing of all the migration files. Simply exclude the files from the directory listing that appear in versions. Apply the rest in order within a single transaction, plus an entry into **schema_migrations** for every migration applied. If successful, the transaction will ensure everything is consistent.

I have used this approach in Python, with each schema migration file being a plain **.sql** file. The overall process was a bash script if I recall.

This doesn't handle rollbacks, but the reverse is easily conceptualised based on this format. The more tricky part is working the rollback code into the same SQL migration file in a meaningful way.